# What is the preferred way to mutate in swr?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, swr

```
const getKey = (pageNumber: number, previousPageData: FileFetchRes) => {
    if (previousPageData && !previousPageData.pageInfo.nextPage) {
      return null;
    }
    return `/file?pageNumber=${pageNumber}&folderId=${folderId}&count=${count}`;
  };
  const func = (url: string) => {
    return axiosInstance()
      .get(url)
      .then(data => data.data);
  };
  return useSWRInfinite(getKey, func);
```

--

```
  const {data, mutate: buttonMutate} = useFetchFile({folderId: 0, count: 30});
  const {mutate: swrMutate} = useSWRConfig();
  console.log(data);

Map {"$inf$/file?pageNumber=0&folderId=0&count=30" => {"_c": undefined, "_i": false, "_k": "$inf$/file?pageNumber=0&folderId=0&count=30", "data": undefined, "error": [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401], "isLoading": false, "isValidating": false}}
```

I use swr with the code above. When I perform any task, the cache accumulates as shown below. One thing I am curious about is

Why is $inf$ << attached to the cache?

When using swrMutate globally, you need to add $inf&/. Is it necessary to use it like this?

```
swrMutate('$inf$/file?pageNumber=0&folderId=0&count=30', undefined);
```

When trying to call all caches that start with /file, can't the pageNumber, count, and folderId parameters be called first, all caches for the file at once? Daily page number = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and count=30, 20, 10

When i need to initialize all data in /file?*

```
swrMutate('$inf$/file?pageNumber=0&folderId=0&count=30', undefined);
swrMutate('$inf$/file?pageNumber=1&folderId=0&count=30', undefined);
swrMutate('$inf$/file?pageNumber=2&folderId=0&count=30', undefined);
swrMutate('$inf$/file?pageNumber=3&folderId=0&count=30', undefined);
swrMutate('$inf$/file?pageNumber=3&folderId=0&count=10', undefined);
swrMutate('$inf$/file?pageNumber=3&folderId=0&count=10', undefined);
```

I think it's strange that it has to be reset for every situation, and there must be another way.